# How can I update the block content programmatically?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have created a block plugin.

`/src/Plugin/Block/Myblock`

```
/**
 * Provides a 'Download component' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "my_custom_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("My custom block"),
 * )
 */
class Myblock extends BlockBase {
  // Other code
}
```

The above block has a settings form also where I am uploading some files to the block.

I placed this block in two different regions on a page with different settings. (Uploaded different files)

Now I want to update the content of one of them i-e `add a new file` programmatically.

How will I do that? Because I can't load the block and update the field and save the block again because both returns me the same id `my_custom_block`.

```
$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('block_content')->load('my_custom_block'));
```

And also this returns me null.

Any idea how will I do that? Just like we update the nod entity, I want to update an instance of this block plugin.

**Updated code:**

I get the block like this

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
 if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    /** @var \Drupal\layout_builder\Field\LayoutSectionItemList $layout */
    $layout = $node->get('layout_builder__layout');
    $block = $layout->getSection(0)->getComponent('1bb8e7b4-8253-40bc-a1f9-7f02e90edb2f')->getPlugin();
    $block->setConfigurationValue('file', ['6338, 6336']);
 }
```

Now how will I save the node using the block new configuration values?

I tried this.

```
 $node->get('layout_builder__layout')->getSection(0)->getComponent('1bb8e7b4-8253-40bc-a1f9-7f02e90edb2f')->setConfiguration($block->getConfiguration());
 $node->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Placed blocks are stored in the config entity `block`. The IDs are more or less unpredictable but you can load the blocks by specifying properties:

```
$entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$blocks = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('block')->loadByProperties([
  'plugin' => 'my_custom_block',
  'region' => $region,
  'theme'  => $theme,
]);
```

A code example to load all blocks placed for the custom block plugin, do some checks and modify the settings:

```
$entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$blocks = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('block')->loadByProperties([
  'plugin' => 'my_custom_block',
]);

foreach ($blocks as $block) {
  if ($block->getRegion() == 'my_region') {
    $settings = $block->get('settings');
    // modify settings
    $block->set('settings', $settings);
    $block->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: How will I get the the region of the block instance. I am using layout builder.

Comment: If you don't know the region when you query the blocks you can check that later. See the second code example.

Comment: Layout modules can store block configuration in different places. If you don't find the placed block with this method I would export the config and search for the plugin id in the config YAML files to locate the config object.

Comment: This will not work if I place two instances in the same region?

Comment: The first loadByProperties() example returns then both instances.

Comment: `$blocks = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('block')->loadByProperties([
  'plugin' => 'my_custom_block',
]);` this returns me an empty array.

Comment: As said before if the configured blocks are not stored in the standard location then export the entire config, locate the config object containing your block settings and modify it in a similar way.

Comment: even if it is placed on a node using layout builder?

Comment: The block is placed on the node using layout builder. Not from the blocks interface or using a content type. So this will not be exported in a config file.

Comment: OK, this is also possible, storing the block config in a node as field data.

Comment: Can you please explain this in your answer?

Comment: This is the first time I've looked at the code of the layout_builder module. It's amazing how fast you can check what a complex D8 module is doing by just seeing the scaffolding of the module. It does obviously define a field type to store the section data per node. The default field name is `layout_builder__layout`. So an example how to get the block configs from a node:  `$components = Node::load(1)->get('layout_builder__layout')->getSection(0)->getComponents()`. If you've found the block you can modify the component, set it in the field the same way you've got it and then save the node.

Comment: I have updated my question. we are nearer to the solution. Only last step left. Can you please check?

Comment: The field type defines the property `section`. So you should be able to get the section from there and store it again: `$node->get('layout_builder__layout')->get($delta)->section = $section`.